# 'Just now': past, future or both?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, time

I only use it speaking of something that has just been done, i.e. in the very near past.

> I've finished washing the dishes just now.

Can it be used also speaking of something that is about to be done, i.e. in the immediate future?

> I am going shopping just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is *no*, you can't use "just now" to refer to the immediate future.

However, you *can* use "just now" to refer to the action in progress (in the present). So your second sentence, while not common, is not strictly wrong (depending on the context).

For example:

> A: I see that you are on your way out the door. Want to grab a coffee?
>
> B: I'm sorry, I can't. *I'm going shopping just now*.
>
> A: No problem. Maybe later.

The reason that this works is because the action is in progress (present progressive tense). By contrast, a future tense would *not* be appropriate:

> *I will go shopping just now.
>
> *I will be going shopping just now.